# azure ml web service request not working in java

Tags: java, android, azure, web, service

i'm working on a mobile app project and we created a machine learning experiment and deployed it as a web service then we get URL and api key then we failed to use them, we need a code in java as we work on android app any help ?

here where i call for Azure ML Client
then i got this error

Comment: You want a complete program without sharing details and you want someone to do whole thing instead of you.

Comment: Add some code snippet you've worked on.

Comment: Is the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/machine-learning-consume-web-services) sample code in Java helpful for you? What issues did you get?

Comment: here where i call for Azure ML Client
then i got this error

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMpgn.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d113V.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ei9EI.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGUiD.png